# What's happening" web part in Sharepoint 2013 community site shows only count upto 20 members

Tags: 2013, web-part, community-site

﻿I have sharepoint 2013 On-premise infrastructure with June 2016 CU installed .. " What's Happening" webpart with no customizations shows only members count upto 20. When number of joiners exceeds more than 20, webpart always show 20..

I checked on different sites in the web application issue remains the same ..

Can you please help me with information , Is this know issue with the product ? Is this going to resolve with any patch ?

Many thanks for your help in advance ..